# Add custom data while creating WooCommerce customer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding woocommerce customer programmatically using wc_create_new_customer function, first name, last name, email is added successfully, but custom fields are not adding.
I have tried two ways
1st one:

```
$email= $arr_item->email;
enter code here$username = strstr($arr_item->email, ‘@’, true);
$password = wp_generate_password();

$args = array(
“first_name” => $arr_item->first_name,
“billing_first_name” => $arr_item->first_name,
“last_name” => $arr_item->last_name,
“billing_last_name” => $arr_item->last_name,
“billing_email” => $arr_item->email,
“billing_phone” => $arr_item->phone,
“agency_name” => $arr_item->agency_name,
“billing_company” => $arr_item->agency_name,
“agency_country” => $arr_item->agency_country,
“agency_city” => $arr_item->agency_city,
“agency_state” => $arr_item->agency_state
);
$customer_id = wc_create_new_customer( $email, $username, $password, $args );
```

2nd one

```
$customer_id = wc_create_new_customer( $email, $username, $password );
update_user_meta( $customer_id, ‘agency_name’,$arr_item->agency_name);
update_user_meta( $customer_id, ‘billing_company’, $arr_item->agency_name);
update_user_meta( $customer_id, ‘agency_country’, $arr_item->agency_country);
update_user_meta( $customer_id, ‘agency_city’, $arr_item->agency_city);
update_user_meta( $customer_id, ‘agency_state’,$arr_item->agency_state);
```

I am trying to add custom field user meta table while creating a customer using wc_create_new_customer
So that I can access these data using get_user_meta().

Please help if anyone has any ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi everyone,

I am still facing issue, is there anyone to help me.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking for an answer to this question:

Overview: To create a new customer for your store you create a WP User using `wc_create_new_customer()` followed by adding their personal details to their `WC_Customer` instance.

Example:

```php
// Create customer.
$customer_id = wc_create_new_customer(
  sanitize_email( 'email@example.test' ),
  'Password123'
);

// Check for an error in the creation.
if ( is_wp_error( $customer_id ) ) {
  throw new ErrorException( $customer_id->get_error_message() );
}

// Get customers WC_Customer instance.
$customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id );

// Set our customer's meta values using WC's CRUD methods.
$customer->set_first_name( 'Jane' );
$customer->set_last_name( 'Bloggs' );
$customer->set_billing_email( 'email@example.test' );
$customer->set_billing_first_name( 'Jane' );
$customer->set_billing_last_name( 'Bloggs' );
$customer->set_billing_address_1( 'The Hawthorns' );
$customer->set_billing_address_2( 'Halfords Lane' );
$customer->set_billing_city( 'West Bromwich' );
$customer->set_billing_postcode( 'B71 4LF' );
$customer->set_billing_country( 'GB' );
$customer->set_billing_phone( '0000 000 0000' );

// Save customer's metadata to the WC Customer instance.
$customer->save();
```

Your customers details will show in the Users tab of the WP Admin and in their account details.

Answer (score -2):

You need to save a customer. Add this 2 lines at the end.

```
$customer = get_user_by('id', $customer_id);
$customer->save();
```